# Using Varjo Aero without steam stations

Tags: virtual-reality, steamvr

I am currently struggling with setting for a new Varjo Aero. I suppose to only watch 3D or 360 videos in the equipment, so I only need a video player for this little VR headset. I don't have steam stations for now, and unfortunately, I found softwares on steamvr(using openvr) all need stations. Is there any video player I can turn to?

I've tried some VR applications on steam like skybox. When I tried to launch these applications, all I could see through my headset was a stationary vision of pure grey. Moving head or so didn't work at all. I also downloaded skybox directly from it official website, but that doesn't apply to Varjo Aero because the headset is wired and connected to pc directly instead of through nets.